# Function of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is the following relation true:

$\int g(X,Y) ~~ dP = \int g(x,y) ~~dF_{X,Y}$

Comment: Is it so called the push-forward measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if by $F_{X,Y}$ you mean $F_{X,Y}(A\times B):=P[X\in A,Y\in B]$ (along with appropriate conditions on the rest of the notation). You can prove it like in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640358/equality-between-two-integrals/2640448#2640448).

Comment: could you please tell me what are the required conditions?